# How to prevent users from calling public annotated methods

Tags: java

I am currently using the javax.websocket library from Jetty. The websocket class is to be used by defining certain annotations over different methods as handlers for different events:

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class MyWebSocket {

        @OnOpen
        public void onWebSocketConnect(Session sess) { }

        @OnMessage
        public void onWebSocketText(String text) { }

        @OnClose
        public void onWebSocketClose(CloseReason reason) { }

        @OnError
        public void onWebSocketError(Throwable cause) { }
}
```

The problem is that these annotated handler methods must have the `public` modifier specified by the library. How should I stop users from calling these methods that they are not supposed to be calling?

Comment: What do you mean by user? Do you mean other people on your project?

Comment: If you make the private default constructor in this class. In that case will the @ClientEndpoint annotation will work ??

Comment: This class should still be public and visible to anyone, but the annotated methods should not be actively called by anyone. And yes, private default constructor is possible.

Comment: thn making class final with private default constructor will prevent public methods as they are not static except reflection.